# Write on an image and export as jpg

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm looking for a way to allow users to write on a image within web browser and allow me to save on the server the generated image.
I use PHP for server side.

Users should be able just to write on the image and change font-family/font-size/font-color/position, no more.

I've seen the Pixrl API but that software is too complex and does too many things.

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is you can provide a text field for text and another for image browse
After submitting of this form using GD library you can generate the final image with text.
Please read here http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Or

you can go through HTML5 canvas